# RewriteRule that will force a trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I have a folder [contact-us]

```
mydomain.com/contact-us/
```

Im planning to remove this folder and will just add a contact-us.php

```
mydomain.com/contact-us.php
```

How can I create a RewriteRule that will map

```
mydomain.com/contact-us/ -> mydomain.com/contact-us.php
```

(Note I want to force a trailing slash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ http://domain.com/contact-us/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us/?$ /contact-us.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

This way is someone type: `contact-us` or `contact-us/` it will go to your contact-us.php

Comment: It works but it doesnt add / at the end of the URL I want it to automatically add / at the end `mydomain.com/contact-us` <- no / at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^contact_us/$ /contact_us.php [QSA]
```

I can't remember if you need a `/` at the start, so if this doesn't work try `^/contact_us/$`